# How can I calculate the Poisson ratio of an amorphous material with LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, amorphous-materials

I noticed that we can calculate the Poisson ratio of a **crystalline metals** with LAMMPS. I wonder if we can use that example for a **metallic glass**! If no, is there any other way, with another software?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: it would be nice to give a reference to "I noticed that we can calculate the Poisson ratio..."

Comment: @CodyAldaz thanks for attention. One can find the file of "in.elastic" in directory like it in their computer "...\LAMMPS 64-bit 22Aug2018-MPI\Examples\ELASTIC\in.elastic". In the first line of the file of "in.elastic", it is written, "Compute elastic constant tensor for a crystal". Moreover, in the 7th line of the same file, it is written "must be modified for different crystal structures". According to these, it seems that this file can just calculate the Poisson ratio of the crystalline material.

Comment: By the way, there is a LAMMPS chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps. Please check it out and say hello at least once so that you become a member of the room!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, and read [here](https://matmatch.com/learn/property/isotropy-anisotropy), metallic glasses akin to crystalline metals are **isotropic**. To this end, if we use the script provided in the examples of LAMMPS, to what extent we can secure the results that we want, i.e Poisson Ratio, Young's modulus, etc.

---

<sub>Note: This was an answer written originally by the person that asked the question, but since that user deleted the question, it seems we need to re-post the answer in order for the answer to exit the unanswered queue.</sub>